# Dynamic function calls based on value

Tags: typescript

Tried to find this everywhere, but didn't manage. First I'm wondering if this is even possible.

So I have a few data types that are similar:

```js
enum DataType {
    A = 'A',
    B = 'B',
}
interface DataA {
    id: number;
    type: DataType.A;
    fieldA: string;
}
interface DataB {
    id: number;
    type: DataType.B;
    fieldB: string;
}
```

And both of these data types are saved differently:

```js
const saveDataA = (data: DataA) => {};
const saveDataB = (data: DataB) => {};
```

but the entry point is a single function `saveData: (data: DataA | DataB) => void`.
I've managed to do this with switch statements:

```js
const saveData = (data: DataB | DataA) => {
    switch(data.type) {
        case DataType.A:
            return saveDataA(data);
        case DataType.B:
            return saveDataB(data);
    }
}
```

This approach works, but it doesn't scale well - for every new `DataType` I need to add new `case`. Further more, if I want to add say `updateData`, `deleteData` etc.. I need to repeat these switch cases in every generic Data function.

In JS I could do something like this:

```js
const saveFuncMap = {
  A: saveDataA,
  B: saveDataB,
}

const saveData = (data) => {
  return saveFuncMap[data.type](data);
}
```

And then have a map for every action with these data types

But I couldn't manage to get to this with typescript since having `saveFuncMap[data.type]` doesn't collapse the data type to a specific type, it's still a union

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/N5kXdW) meet your needs?  If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TypeScript doesn't really have direct support for what I call "correlated [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) types".  This is the subject of [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581).

In your case, you want to write a single line of code, `saveFuncMap[data.type](data)`, `data`, a value of a union type `DataA | DataB`, appears multiple times.  The compiler analyzes this at the type level alone, and does not pay attention to the *identities* of the values.  So imagine you had two values instead, `data1` and `data2`, both of type `DataA | DataB`, and tried to write `saveFuncMap[data1.type](data2)`.  The compiler doesn't allow that because, for all anyone knows, `data1.type` and `data2.type` are different.  So it warns you that such a call is unsafe. Of course, *we* know that `data1` and `data2` are really just `data`, so the call *is* safe, but the compiler cannot easily be made to see that.

---

The recommended approach to take in situations like this is to refactor away from unions to [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html), where the operations are all expressed in terms of some "basic" key-value interface, and generic [indexed accesses](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) into that interface or [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) over that interface.  This is described in detail in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109).

For your example the recommended refactoring looks like this. The basic key-value mapping interface is:

```
interface DataMap {
  [DataType.A]: { id: number, fieldA: string },
  [DataType.B]: { id: number, fieldB: string }
}
```

And then you can combine your `DataA` and `DataB` types into a single `Data` *distributive object type*:

```
type Data<K extends DataType> =
  { [P in K]: { type: P } & DataMap[P] }[K]
```

If you want to refer to `DataA` and `DataB` by those names, you can:

```
type DataA = Data<DataType.A>
type DataB = Data<DataType.B>
```

And then what you were calling `DataA | DataB` is just `Data<DataType>`.  (You can verify that this produces the appropriate [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) by distributing the `Data<K>` operation over the union `DataA | DataB`.  That's why it's called a distributive object type.)

Now we can take your `saveFuncMap` value and give it a type which is explicitly a mapped type over `K` in `DataType`, and references `Data<K>`:

```
const saveFuncMap: { [K in DataType]: (data: Data<K>) => void } = {
  A: saveDataA,
  B: saveDataB,
}
```

That's enough for the compiler to see `saveData()`'s implementation as valid:

```
const saveData = <K extends DataType>(data: Data<K>) => {
  return saveFuncMap[data.type](data);
}
// const saveData: <K extends DataType>(data: Data<K>) => void

saveData({ type: DataType.A, id: 123, fieldA: "AbC" }); 
saveData({ type: DataType.B, id: 456, fieldB: "DeF" });
```

---

If you need `saveFuncMap` to have different return types for each method, you can capture this information in a separate "basic" interface:

```
const saveDataA = (data: DataA) => data.fieldA;
const saveDataB = (data: DataB) => data.fieldB.length;

interface SaveFuncMapReturn {
  A: string;
  B: number;
}
```

And then make sure the `saveFuncMap` mapped type is written in terms of both `Data` and `SaveFuncMapReturn`:

```
const saveFuncMap: {
  [K in DataType]: (data: Data<K>) => SaveFuncMapReturn[K]
} = {
  A: saveDataA,
  B: saveDataB,
}

saveData({ type: DataType.A, id: 123, fieldA: "AbC" }).toUpperCase();
saveData({ type: DataType.B, id: 456, fieldB: "DeF" }).toFixed(1);
```

If you don't want to redundantly mention those return types multiple times you can instead define a version of `saveFuncMap` without annotation, and use [the `typeof` type query operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/typeof-types.html) to compute the appropriate basic mapping type, and then annotate the "real" `saveFuncMap` accordingly:

```
const _saveFuncMap = {
  A: saveDataA,
  B: saveDataB,
}

type SaveFuncMapReturn =
  { [K in DataType]: ReturnType<typeof _saveFuncMap[K]> }

const saveFuncMap:
  { [K in DataType]: (data: Data<K>) => SaveFuncMapReturn[K] } = _saveFuncMap;
```

This amounts to the same thing, but now you can just change, say, `saveDataA`, and `SaveFuncMapReturn.A` will change automatically.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.1.6#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAUPkkhMAK5hIAiIALiACoCeMyBxxAgkgLxIDknfgBoiHAEK8B4kWIC+hYgEtgtCACcAZgmQ16AWRAw8Y4gG09jFhAB0nALoAuPEiUATZ+TAAjDcKSaShAYbpzOULTqKgDmSHKiHEgWdFasNuJOLu6eFL7q-oHBbuLhkTFx8opItNbUKQA8ANIkAB5qwG5QdfTMrAB8vKYuZgAKrsBIjZm41dbOY3JIAGTdIIYwo-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-nMz0ka9zhUbRn30fBTFJn9-pJkoLQQG4LIgbq4NIHBEE2AADNxlR8Ti6JCVQIliYZ0QXWCarnGAMBkGobgKRw60NcyD4Aq50phZ5cUbX5DlHbaUubmFfqRdE0WxdDJ5IAA+kuiXrJVM7VR1nDNcQ9U1X5zW8RwfxYqdSUXYMM5ZulEz9ZkXPWPUfznKcBvO7NUwDAoOu2YbM1GI4qUezm3vOBLRZ5S+BVG8V86lVMVZ8MH6kxzA2si7rDVdYON57T0o4pyAk4vjWHATTp0dnXNm4LbuXkRxwR6izbTlbd1O23vttdDQ0aejRnRcXVd3aw-dg+PUj-V2KRzjvXRcrwYhyGoQDKqhpqINsRDnBYdxkeuqKd3wyviOEcjTWoxRNE78U2PMYfHwE0TJMyY8gwtTOmPFCByCAA)

Answer (score 2):

When you attempt to call a function with a union type in TypeScript, it's treated as though you're attempting to call an *intersection* of that function type. This often causes problems,for example you may have encountered it when attempting to work with array methods like this:

```js
function removeEmpty(arr: string[] | number[]) {
  // Error: This expression is not callable
  return arr.filter(Boolean);
}
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.1.6#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAJwKYFs4DdUFF0AOUAngBQCGyyAXIgM5TIxgDmA2gLqIA+iYI6AEapknAJSIA3gChEiAPTzEuKnBqIAKgAsYdRKgAeBNHTrwkuvnCiII5ADb3yg+6lkpUUEMiSVkAOmAYeygRUgAhODhXcjAxAG5pAF9pIA)

In the specific case of array methods, [TypeScript 5.2](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-5-2-beta/#easier-method-usage-for-unions-of-arrays) is changing the behaviour to allow it to work. But *only* for array methods. In cases like yours, 5.2 won't help.

However, you can use your function map approach with a simple type assertion, to tell the TypeScript compiler information that it's missing.

For example, this approach works:

```js
enum DataType {
    A = 'A',
    B = 'B',
}
interface DataA {
    id: number;
    type: DataType.A;
    fieldA: string;
}
interface DataB {
    id: number;
    type: DataType.B;
    fieldB: string;
}

const saveDataA = (data: DataA) => {};
const saveDataB = (data: DataB) => {};

const saveFuncMap = {
  A: saveDataA,
  B: saveDataB,
};

type Data = Parameters<typeof saveFuncMap[keyof typeof saveFuncMap]>[0];

const saveData = (data: Data) => {
  const saveFn = saveFuncMap[data.type] as (arg: typeof data) => void;
  saveFn(data);
}
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAIghgFzgFQJ4AdhQN4CgoFQCCUAvFAOREUA0+hAQmZQ7bgL64CWICwATgDM4AYyzwkJPIShcAJgC4o4CACMBAbnoEEGYEoko9AOiJaZgrsAA2cokoDOCfjwDmWzjz5DR4xHCZpQnklFXV+c0JdTAN-NExjBkiCSxs5BkdnNw9cXBEAexAnKAc4ADdgQxJyAAo5f1jJAEoyAD4cdi0CooQS8sr-Jlr6pEaAltJ27E7c7uLSioAxMBARAFk4dGYg+z6KqroCDL2BpAY6GdxovyRmAAU4fjgIYG8HAB5r-MET5dWN9AAbQA1sBUN8oF8fgtgH91psALqtQEABgRWjyhXm-UMzDqDVg-gmU3oc16MMWIGYFJW8KBIzgxmuCKgcAcUBqj1cSihUAZxKgZXy8kiFJA+KQTRyQA)

I've used the [`Parameters`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterstype) utility type to construct that union of different `Data` objects based on your save function map, which saves having to define that separately.

I can understand if you're reluctant to use a type assertion, given they break type safety. But they are a useful tool for cases like this, where it's necessary to give the TypeScript compiler additional information, and when the assumptions a type assertion is based on are sound.

I often find it's helpful to leave myself a comment for later, explaining any assumptions underlying a type assertion and explaining why it's safe.

---

In a comment, you said you need this to also work with `save` functions that return a type other than `void`. You can manage this by making your function generic. For example:

```js
type Result<T extends Data> = ReturnType<typeof saveFuncMap[T["type"]]>;

const saveData = <T extends Data>(data: T): Result<T> => {
  const saveFn = saveFuncMap[data.type] as (arg: Data) => Result<T>;
  return saveFn(data);
}

//

const resultA = saveData({ id: 0, type: DataType.A, fieldA: 'string' }); // ResultA
const resultB = saveData({ id: 1, type: DataType.B, fieldB: 'string' }); // ResultB

const resultUnion = saveData({ // ResultA | ResultB
  id: 2,
  type: Math.random() > 0.5 ? DataType.A : DataType.B,
  fieldA: 'string',
  fieldB: 'string',
});
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAIghgFzgFQJ4AdhQN4CgpQCCUAvFAOSHkA0+UAQqRfTbgL64CWICwATgDM4AYyzwkxPAU4ATAFxRwEAEb8A3HQQZgC8Sm0A6QhoIDOwADYzCCgM4I+3AOYaO3XoJFYASsFtgLBElNbV1EfUwjVy4efiFRWHDGKShZBSVVPhMoLUwwpDRI+myzSxl6OwdnaPc4ryhff0DkkLzEgsNi9lxcYQB7EHsoWzgAN2A9YjIAChlw-LhCAEoFRoCg0gA+KGnsHNCoOaQDXOA2JY1+wYRhsYmkpln59rh6FYa-dcYSbd39tqOcBO2nOGl6AyGI3GADEwCBhABZODoJgpGy3caTWgECoY+5Iei0Nhg04vJgABTgfDgEGAHlsAB5Tn0BHjYfCkegANoAa2AqBZ-2AgqhwHZiORAF1NlyAAySjSktaBBnIKDAAAevBAMlsL22ZF8CDAfBAhWATO0Iru4s5XOQXIARKdHZLpWCrpC7nomKr1VrQLr9U8kApkO9lQhVQbtilPTdRdCQExE3CJdzAcDMJKoHA9dMqU4Fksth8mlHkJtsnw6Sbk4mQCG4BdurgAPRtnrxqA18tTPF6P5pKCy6hChbmoxj0pWdHkeyOEBOchQUFQDtl9aEcHXHufZop73hIfyKAARjHpwnnWn5isuPnVSXK7XG8j9C7EJuvfWAFUQJwAyHpix57G++4bAAPpuzR0MOABM2LjlASIIAAFgY1I6n0EDTCW2yygYACsUAAPwvJOxDXkUSEztYCiPouy60Xe5QMQuzisKCuBAA)

This feels like one of those examples where a `oneof` operator would be useful, to force this function to only use a single member of the `Data` union type as its generic type. However, this is not currently possible in TypeScript, which is why I included the example with a union generic type.

There has been [an open issue to add a `oneof` operator](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27808) since 2018.

The potential for generic types to be instantiated with unions is most typically a problem with functions that have multiple arguments that use the generic type, so I don't think you're likely to run into it here. However, it's clear that you stripped this example down quite thoroughly (always appreciated in a question, so thanks for that) so I think this is worth mentioning.

Here's an example of a generic function with two arguments going wrong:

```js
interface OptionsA {
  keepFieldA?: boolean;
}
interface OptionsB {
  keepFieldB?: boolean;
}

// I haven't actually used the options argument, but hopefully that doesn't obscure the demonstration
const saveDataA = (data: DataA, options?: OptionsA): ResultA => ({ type: data.type});
const saveDataB = (data: DataB, options?: OptionsB): ResultB => ({ type: data.type});

type Options<T extends Data> = Parameters<typeof saveFuncMap[T["type"]]>[1];
type Result<T extends Data> = ReturnType<typeof saveFuncMap[T["type"]]>;

const saveData = <T extends Data>(data: T, options?: Options<T>): Result<T> => {
  const saveFn = saveFuncMap[data.type] as (dataArg: Data, optionsArg: Options<T>) => Result<T>;
  return saveFn(data, options);
}

//

const resultA = saveData({ id: 0, type: DataType.A, fieldA: 'string' }); // ResultA
const resultB = saveData({ id: 1, type: DataType.B, fieldB: 'string' }); // ResultB

// Because the generic type is a union, the types of the
// two arguments don't match 99% of the time in this case
const resultUnion = saveData({ // ResultA | ResultB
  id: 2,
  type: Math.random() < 0.99 ? DataType.A : DataType.B,
  fieldA: 'string',
  fieldB: 'string',
}, {
  keepFieldB: true,
});
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAIghgFzgFQJ4AdhQN4CgpQCCUAvFAOSHkA0+UAQqRfTbgL64CWICwATgDM4AYyzwkxPAU4ATAFxRwEAEb8A3HQQZgC8Sm0A6QhoIDOwADYzCCgM4I+3AOYaO3XoJFYA8ugScAexBbSToAa2BgdAAxcytCAH4FZQCAi2A4EFcuHn4hUSgAJWBbMAsEUIItTF1EfUwjbPc8r1g6xikoWQUlVT4TKGqdNqQ0BvoBs0sZejsHZybczwLffyDbDvDImLiZpKgUtIys9hyPfKxi0vLNqu1a0cMJ09wAeleoAEkoAAs4ADdQOQEFARAgwHALBZUFAwLZgDJBj8sAE-IFgqC+E5IKAENQDmAQT9UcABGVoUjEFAZAESiBgVAAspbMIwHwsAhkdTgBB1g5EOjcMI+VBbADgHpiGQABQyOoPOCEfGotbBfardEhACUCiuZQqpAAfFBpdhBvdqXUDEM2FqNMLgiCxYC9IwZXKkAr6Mq0et1b7gvQdUUSvq3cbTeaapakNbtLaNEKRc7gNEwCBhABZODoJidGyi8WS2gEWaFl3tWhsRNDEZwJgABTgfDgEGAHlsAB4hgEBOXU+mszmANoRVC9qPACcptMZ7PoAC6huHAAYFxpaxr1p3kFBgAAPXggGS2OvGshNlttjvd7TT8WzofoYfIYcAIiGb4XS+HAEZ17gtZ6uUO57oeoAnmeTDFOCfAgGMwC3pg96Ao+84vu+n7foaiYOvY-Z6EwoEHkekF6IasrylAyA+qqtj+nRO6GsGwEIExRo4HQeFOg+IBMDOg7oR6cBxpgC6gqelESFiCq0ZqhAyVAW7BExWocaxTEDOysF8TOIBSXAcnrHaLzvLgSaOlA7LXAaZApnokbdFAK74kMCoIUY+JTPECjkPYjggE45BQAmUDvCGNmEBZ+HWWG-FFnUjnyFAv6uRaeged6UDeTMvn+c4wWheFrH0OZ4X0MAwhwHCHJck4oD8JwwiTl0p71um6KuVyQynhOnLAG8HwIAA7gEmLYm2PCnjS9IghAiDCD8UAAJzLQApIyfb9YMnBtl0fGcpwp5VfC0UgrF5QAKogOi8UVkgkbFaG5TEAAPhFYZ0E5ABMJaTgo2acgYLbHgEEDSmpnbOQYq1QAkdYecQ7lPH9OUFn58yBawpi7GWGMBUFVb4p0ERRLE0xlg4YDAFWJlAA)

It's possible to add an additional constraint between argument types by using a destructured tuple type. Here's my attempt at that, though I wasn't able to get it working without adding an additional type assertion within the `saveData` function:

```js
type SaveDataParams<T extends DataType> = Parameters<typeof saveFuncMap[T]>;

type Result<T extends DataType> = ReturnType<typeof saveFuncMap[T]>;

const saveData = <T extends DataType>(...[data, options]: SaveDataParams<T>): Result<T> => {
  const saveFn = saveFuncMap[data.type] as (...args: SaveDataParams<DataType>) => Result<T>;
  return saveFn(...[data, options] as SaveDataParams<DataType>);
}

//

const resultA = saveData({ id: 0, type: DataType.A, fieldA: 'string' }); // ResultA
const resultB = saveData({ id: 1, type: DataType.B, fieldB: 'string' }); // ResultB

// The options argument prevents anything but DataB being used in the data argument
const resultUnion = saveData({ // ResultA | ResultB
  id: 2,
  type: Math.random() < 0.99 ? DataType.A : DataType.B,
  fieldA: 'string',
  fieldB: 'string',
}, {
  keepFieldB: true,
});
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAIghgFzgFQJ4AdhQN4CgpQCCUAvFAOSHkA0+UAQqRfTbgL64CWICwATgDM4AYyzwkxPAU4ATAFxRwEAEb8A3HQQZgC8Sm0A6QhoIDOwADYzCCgM4I+3AOYaO3XoJFYA8ugScAexBbSToAa2BgdAAxcytCAH4FZQCAi2A4EFcuHn4hUSgAJWBbMAsEUIItTF1EfUwjbPc8r1g6xikoWQUlVT4TKGqdNqQ0BvoBs0sZejsHZybczwLffyDbDvDImLiZpKgUtIys9hyPfKxi0vLNqu1a0cMJ09wAeleoAEkoAAs4ADdQOQEFARAgwHALBZUFAwLZgDJBj8sAE-IFgqC+E5IKAENQDmAQT9UcABGVoUjEFAZAESiBgVAAspbMIwHwsAhkdTgBB1g5EOjcMI+VBbADgHpiGQABQyOoPOCEfGotbBfardEhACUCiuZQqpAAfFBpdhBvdqXUDEM2FqNMLgiCxYC9IwZXKkAr6Mq0et1b7gvQdUUSvq3cbTeaapakNbtLaNEKRc7gNEwCBhABZODoJidGyi8WS2gEWaFl3tWhsRNDKAAZSLdQACnA+HAILYADzIKDAAAevBAMlsI3qwGNZBbbYgwA8XaGAQE5dT6azOYA2sgALqGmvaEPXBDd3sD0DD0djcdMYrgvggS+dhdLlNpjPZ9CbneJh32Zd6JjHv2g7nnol6GtKBiQeuHpwD6qq2FuCgNhWSBTu2XbIIawZ6uU3YTsanQ-k64rRCATAvqu77QVaQxbqCI4QZBrZOLYSGNqhrboZ2oHaFhRoHvqeEDOyt5kS+ICMQY1FIHBmp0XAI7IRKzacR23F1GBdovO8uBJo6UDsoeUp-nUkbdFAAAM+JDAql5GPiUzxAo5D2I4IBOOQUAJlA7wCeUhB6b+hlhuR7FwGZ8hQAAjNZFo8eMDm7GWLnzO5nneb5OEIPQum+cgXIqpqmLYjOPBQOg7KAjwI6ZKgnLOASIKugcwANXCCJdGRnJYDBxU4jwgUgsF5QAKogOioUoeFZqZaG-lQAAPn52V0OZABMJZRsM2acgYbZDgEEDSlqUCdpZBgAJwXVACQXoYxC2U8m2OdYzmuc4rCmElb2pR5Vb4p0ERRLE0xlg4YDAFWWlAA)

Comment: I like this, but I have one issue. If these functions return different type: `saveDataA: (...) => SavedDataA` and `saveDataB: (...) => SavedDataB`. how can I make it work with return types?

Comment: I've edited my answer to include another solution, which supports return types like that